# Custom functions loaded from config files

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some javascript that exposes some limited functionality on the client-side but each function is configured on the server-side. A simple example of this is exposing an equality function, allowing the client-side to compare 2 strings.

The functions that will be exposed should be relatively basic (equals, not equals, less than etc.). Ideally though, it would be nice if we could easily append more functions as we need them later on.

I'm wondering, would it be better to have some core javascript and then append on more javascript i.e.:

Core Logic:

```
var CoreFunctions = {}
```

Appended Logic:

```
CoreFunctions.instruction_map = {
    equals: function(a,b){return a==b;}
}
```

In contrast, would it be better to have the core logic which includes some eval'ish functionality then store functions in JSON:
Core logic:

```
var CoreFunctions = {};

for {var prop in instruction_map) {
    CoreFunctions[prop] = new Function(instruction_map[prop]);
}
```

Appended Logic:

```
instruction_map = {
        'equals': 'return arguments[0]==arguments[1];'
}
```

The goal is to easily add new functionality in the future, in this case it could be something like a not_equals function. Not sure if either of these is the best approach but would love to get some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to have it in the core as eval cannot be truted to work perfectly.

Eval uses functions in a weird way.

There are also some other nuances with eval that you have to be careful about.
From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

For example

> Do not call eval() to evaluate an arithmetic expression; JavaScript
>   evaluates arithmetic expressions automatically

Security is also an issue

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension.

As an alternative, how about this..
You store the core functionality as a separate file, and use an interface to input new code as you need it, which wont take much time to create.
Then write the inputted code to the file (append it).

Edit: If you only have evalish functionality but not eval, then this should be fine, as long as the functionality is not getting variables that are outside its scope. But the same security vulnerabilities remain if you dont check the code. Also if scopes and the dataflow is not planned before writing the code, it can become a nightmare later.

Comment: That sounds completely doable, considering I'll be serving the javascript from our existing Python based web server (Flask).


In addition to this, what if we wanted to allow the client-side to also add some basic functionality. I'm thinking that would have to be eval'd and if that were the case, would it make more sense to unify everything into JSON to be stored in some server-side DB?